# Add multiple values to Perl / JSON object

Tags: json, perl

I'm sure there is a "shortcut" to this problem - which I thought I'd solved, but which now doesn't work. Suggestions please.

Having decoded the JSON object to "$codes", this works:

```
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}->{"singlePay"}=$singlePayments;
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}->{"trialPay"}=$trialPayments;
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}->{"subsPay"}=$subsPayments;
```

but it is somewhat repetative to add 10 entries in this way. I'm SURE I found a solution on SO - which I now can't find. In my script, it is:

```
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}->{
"singlePay"=$singlePayments,
"trialPay"=$trialPayments,
"subsPay"=$subsPayments
};
```

But I get "Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment ..." I have also tried removing the quotes, and using "fat arrows" on the entries to add, but that doesn't help. Probably a "schoolboy error", but where am I going wrong?

(As I operate between "PHP" and "Perl", perhaps this structure only works in PHP)

Also, I need to add another object to the entry, so tried `"affs"={}` and `"affs:"={}` within the brackets ... but that created an error too. I could use the "long" line shown above, but be helpful to do  it all in one operation. Here is the required existing structure:

```
"codes":{
     "product":{
          "ad_id":{
               "itemNo1":{
                    singlePay":"0.00",
                    "trialPay":"0.00",
                    "subsPay":"0.00",
                    "affs":{}
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a new hash/object, you could use the following:

```perl
$codes->{ product }{ ad_id }{ $ad_id } = {
   singlePay => $singlePayments,
   trialPay  => $trialPayments,
   subsPay   => $subsPayments,
   affs      => { },
};
```

To add to an existing hash/object (creating it if it doesn't exist) without clobbering any other existing fields, you could use the following:

```perl
my $dst = $codes->{ product }{ ad_id }{ $ad_id } //= { };

$dst->{ singlePay } = $singlePayments;
$dst->{ trialPay  } = $trialPayments;
$dst->{ subsPay   } = $subsPayments;
$dst->{ affs      } = { };
```

---

We could try other things, like a hash slice.

```perl
$codes->{ product }{ ad_id }{ $ad_id }->@{qw(
   singlePay
   trialPay
   subsPay
   affs
)} = (
   $singlePayments,
   $trialPayments,
   $subsPayments,
   { },
);
```

Not great.

How about merging hashes?

```perl
my $dst = $codes->{ product }{ ad_id }{ $ad_id } //= { };

%$dst = ( %$dst,
   singlePay => $singlePayments,
   trialPay  => $trialPayments,
   subsPay   => $subsPayments,
   affs      => { },
);
```

More expensive, and still not really any better than the solution with which we started.

Finally, how about a multi-variable foreach loop?

```perl
my $dst = $codes->{ product }{ ad_id }{ $ad_id } //= { };

for my ( $k, $v ) (  # 5.36+
   singlePay => $singlePayments,
   trialPay  => $trialPayments,
   subsPay   => $subsPayments,
   affs      => { },
) {
   $dst->{ $k } = $v;
}
```

This is clean, but it's hard to see an advantage (with a fixed number of assignments). And it requires 5.36 which may not be available.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. Of note, is the "//={ }" an actual code line, or is it meant to denote a comment as in 'use this'?) I've detailed below my current "modus operandii"

Comment: Looking at the above again, one uses  a new variable ("$dst" "To add to an exisitng hash / create it ...") How would that be added back into the existing $codes file? If looked at as $codes being the outer "grandparent", and "ad_id" being the parent of multiple "$ad_id" childern,  the latter being the code amended by "$dst" ?

Comment: Actual code. `$x //= EXPR` is similar to `$x = defined( $x ) ? $x : EXPR`

Answer (score 0):

See, I told ya it was "schoolboy". The line:

```
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}->{
```

Should have been:

```
$codes->{"product"}->{"ad_id"}->{"$ad_id"}={
```

(The last short arrow (->) before the curly bracket should have been an equal sign!! Only taken me three hours to spot that typo !!)

Comment: 1) That's still doesn't compile. You'd have also have to change the three `=` to `=>`. 2) That clobbers any existing fields. It's unclear if that's a problem or not, but they did say they wanted to add to an object.

Comment: 2) Yep, I found that one out the hard  way! So what I did - which might not be correct - was to open the existing file, copy the misssing items to variables, and then add them manually. (Another part of the code rebuilds 20 fields in object anyway lest the user has changed them.